# How can I use Basic HTTP Authentication in PHP to access a text file by username and password?

Tags: php, bash, file, shell, authentication

I am new to php programming. I need to create a webpage which get user name and password from user and after verifying it gives access to a particular text file. I have seen the basic on the documentation page and after running it works good for me (however I need to define user name and password):

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

My question here is, I need a bash/shell script which is sending username and password information to this page and then it can **download** a texfile. The text file is in htdocs directory and called "welcome.txt". The bash script command to download the file can be anything like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
wget --user=admin --password=admin http://behzadgarekani.net16.net/connect.php -O -q my-old-bookmarks.txt
```

OR

using `curl`

I'd appreciate if you could help me. There is no force that I must do it in this way. If you have any other suggestion to share this text file will be appreciated.

Edit:

```
<?php

    destroy_foo();
    function destroy_foo()
    {
        unset($GLOBALS[_SERVER]);

        if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {

            unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);

        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {

            unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

        }
    }

    //unset ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] );
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
        echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
        //header('Location: welcome.txt');

        $file = 'welcome.txt';

        if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "admin" && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] =="admin"){

            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                readfile($file);
                destroy_foo();

                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: did you see the example with username and password http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @zod yes. My problem is the text file. How can I redirect it to text file if the username and password is correct?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments , i think after login you want to force download a file

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

for text file

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Comment: Thanks for you reply. There is a problem with downloading. my bash script is downloading text file in format of html file.

Comment: Do I need to delete previous headers because it did not work with that even. The file is html format

Comment: Please have a look at image after download